# Using a thread to capture process output

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using a thread to capture stream output from a process, and then outputting that stream to the eclipse console. The question I have is when to terminate the thread that is doing the stream output.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        private boolean isProcessDone(Process p)
        {
            //not sure what to do here
        }
        public void run()
        {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("executable with output");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            while ( !isProcessDone(p) ) {
                String line;
                if( (line = input.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                if( (line = error.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            input.close();  
            error.close();      
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

My question is what belongs in the `isProcessDone()` function. The example I am basing this off of uses the stream's `ready()` function, but I am unclear whether this will work for programs that either std::err and std::out, but not both. I also tried using

```
try{
    p.exitValue();
    return true;
}catch(IllegalThreadStateException e){}
return false;
```

but then the thread finishes before the while loop has a chance to act on the streams, and the output is lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [Process.waitFor()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) to wait for process completion.

Additionally, you need to consume stdout and stderr *concurrently* in order to avoid blocking and a possible process hang. Consequently you need two threads to read these streams, and to continue reading whilst the streams are available.

See [this Javaworld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) for more info and a `StreamGobbler` implementation to consume the stdout/err.

Comment: I dont want to hang the main process while I send off this task; that is why I am doing this in a thread. Are you saying I will need multiple threads to handle this task?

Comment: If you try to consume stout then stderr, or stderr then stdout (i.e. not concurrently) then you may encounter blocking behaviour, depending on the quantities of output. So regardless of spawning the process in a new thread, you need to consume the stdout/err in separate threads.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation of a (very) confusing Java implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`VerboseProcess`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/apidocs-0.7.5/com/jcabi/log/VerboseProcess.html) from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/threads-VerboseProcess.html) (I'm a developer):

```
String name = new VerboseProcess(
  new ProcessBuilder("executable with output")
).stdout();
```

The only dependency you need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have two threads.  One to handle the I/O and another to wait for process completion (Process.waitFor()) and set a flag telling the I/O thread to quit when it exhausts the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process reading the output in a separate thread, theres an example [here](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/runtime-exec-locks-up)